# Properly casting signed to unsigned

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, unsigned

I'm using a C library that uses unsigned integers as index to some data. But sometimes, functions return those indices as signed in order to return `-1` if the function fails to return an index.*

How do I prevent `implicit conversion changes signedness` warnings and instead, throw runtime errors if the conversion isn't possible? Would you recommend to wrap library functions to use exceptions for error handling and only return proper values?
Is there a standard way to do this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

// pointless c function to demonstrate the question
// parse the string to an unsigned integer, return -1 on failure
int atoui(char const* str) {
    char* pend;
    long int li=strtol(str, &pend, 10);
    if ( errno!=0 || *pend!='\0' || li<0 || li>INT_MAX ) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return li;
    }
}

// --8<---

#include <stdexcept>

// How to do this properly?
unsigned int unsign(int i) {
    if(i<0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Tried to cast negative int to unsigned int");
    } else {
        return static_cast<unsigned>(i);
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned int j=unsign(atoui("42")); // OK
    unsigned int k=unsign(atoui("-7")); // Runtime error
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard library has no such function, but it's easy enough to write such a template:

```
template<typename SInt, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integeral_v<SInt> && std::is_signed_v<SInt>>>
constexpr auto unsigned_cast(Sint i)
{
  if(i < 0) throw std::domain_error("Outside of domain");
  return static_cast<std::make_unsigned_t<SInt>>(i);
}
```

You can also return an `optional` if you don't like throwing exceptions for such trivial matters:

```
template<typename SInt, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integeral_v<SInt> && std::is_signed_v<SInt>>>
constexpr std::optional<std::make_unsigned_t<SInt>> unsigned_cast_opt(Sint i)
{
  if(i < 0) return std::nullopt;
  return static_cast<std::make_unsigned_t<SInt>>(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I can't find any documentation on is_integral_v, only on is_integral, what headers are these in?

Comment: @Gamification It's inside [`std::is_integral` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral): `template< class T > inline constexpr bool is_integral_v = is_integral<T>::value;`

Answer (score 5):

If you want a range check at runtime (i.e. permitting the conversion between types *iff* the value held can be maintained), Boost has [`numeric_cast`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html) that achieves this.

And if you don't want to use Boost, your approach looks decent enough.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I missed that you were using C++, my previous answer assumed C only.

The simplest and most standard way is to use

```
std::optional<unsigned int> index;
```

instead of using -1 or some other sentinel value to represent invalid index. If the index is invalid, you just don't set the optional. Then you can query it with

> index.has_value()

to find out if it is valid or not.

Comment: I'm using a C function from C++ that, as a fact, returns -1 on error. Sorry for not making that more clear in my question.

Comment: You can easily have a wrapper that converts this to std::optional. If the function returns -1 you don't set the optional, otherwise you set it to the value returned.